# How do I install the Bugzilla user guide on my Bugzilla site?

Tags: bugzilla

How do I install the Bugzilla user documentation on my Bugzilla site?  I can't find any reference to installing the documentation locally, and the link on the Bugzilla home page for "Bugzilla User's Guide" is broken.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After incrementally upgrading a Bugzilla installation from 2.22 to 4.4, the `docs_urlbase` parameter (Home -> Administration -> General) became erroneous.  Additionally, after manually running `/opt/bugzilla/docs/makedocs.pl`, it became evident that the RHEL packages `xmlto` and `lynx` needed to be installed in order to successfully generate the Bugzilla documentation.

`yum install lynx xmlto
cd /opt/bugzilla/docs
perl makedocs.pl`

Then I changed `docs_urlbase` from `docs/html/` to `docs/%lang%/html/`.